# How to make vue naviagation guard work after refresh

Tags: vue.js, navigation, vuex, vue-router

```
  if(to.matched.some(record =>to.meta.requiresAuth)){

    if(store.getters.isAuthenticated == true)
    next()

    else next({name: "Login"}) 

  }
 else next()
})
```

So, I have this code for authentication. It works fine, except that when I refresh the page, I can't access it unless I login again. How to make it work on refresh also? Thanks

Comment: You'll want to recheck authentication on refresh, validating a token or checking a session.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I used sessionStorage instead of Vuex store, cuz it keeps the values even after refresh. localStorage didn't work for some reason